# Building MongoDB C++ driver on Windows: boost not found

Tags: windows, mongodb

This is how I'm trying to build C++ driver:

> scons --32 --dynamic-windows --prefix="h:\3rdparty\MongoDB\src\bin\"
>   --cpppath="h:\3rdparty\boost" --libpath="h:\3rdparty\boost\lib32-msvc-12.0\" install-mongoclient

And this is what I get:

> Checking for C++ header file boost/version.hpp... (cached) no
>       can't find boost headers
>
> ```
> ...
> fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/static_assert.hpp': No such file or directory
> ```

I'm positive that my 3rdparty\boost is the right dir: it contains a folder named "boost", which contains all the boost headers. So boost/static_assert.hpp should be resolved for this folder no problem.

What am I doing wrong?

This is the latest driver sources from git repository as of today.

Comment: Can you please include the output of `dir /s /b` after you `cd` to `h:\3rdparty\boost`?

Comment: @npclaudiu: there you go https://gist.github.com/VioletGiraffe/5cfefd427eac78bb049f

Answer (score 0):

Try to compile with

```
... --cpppath="h:\3rdparty\boost\" ...
```

Note backslash `\` at the end.